# Prepending metadata to a var vs. a data structure in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What, effectively, is the difference between these two metadata declarations? Why would you use one over the other?

```
(def a0 ^{:answer-to-everything 42} {:language "ClojureScript"})

(def ^{:answer-to-everything 42} a1 {:language "ClojureScript"})
```

I take it that in the first case the metadata is being prepended to the *map*, while in the second case the metadata is being prepended to the *var*. Assuming I am correct, I still don't understand why you would ever prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in cases where you want to have the metadata follow the value as it's passed from function to function then use the first case. And when you don't use the second:

```
user> (def a0 ^{:answer-to-everything 42} {:language "ClojureScript"})
#'user/a0
user> (def ^{:answer-to-everything 42} a1 {:language "ClojureScript"})
#'user/a1
user> (print-the-metadata-from-a-function a0)
{:answer-to-everything 42}
nil
user> (print-the-metadata-from-a-function a1)
nil
nil
user> (print-the-metadata-from-a-function #'a1)
{:answer-to-everything 42, :line 74, :column 6, :file *cider-repl api*, :name a1, :ns #namespace[user]}
nil
```